# jQueryForm (plugin) on submit do something with form -> $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple forms on one page and I am using [jQueryForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to handle them without page reload. The problem is, i need some visual response that form submit worked or not, so I am changing the border from gray to green if it worked and to red if it did not.

Well, that works with pure jQuery, but not with this plugin, as when I use `$(this)` it refers to function itself.

Does somebody have idea how to do that?

```
var edit_form = {
    dataType: 'json',
    success:    function(output) {
        console.log($(this));
        $form = $(this);
        $form.css("border-color", "green");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $form.css("border-color", "#323131");
        }, 3000);
    },
    error: function(output) {
        console.log($(this));
        $form = $(this);
        $form.css("border-color", "red");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $form.css("border-color", "#323131");
        }, 3000);
    }
};
$('.twitch-form').ajaxForm(edit_form);
```

Console log returns this:

```
[Object, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.7.2", size: function…]
```

Normally for such things I would use `$.post` but I need to be able to upload images with those forms...

Thanks.

Comment: try logging ouput instead of $(this)

Comment: @digitaldouble The output = data returned by file thats being called, which is useless for me, mainly in case of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [plugin documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)(look at the `success` option), the success method gets the form object as the 4th parameter

> **success** 
>   Callback function to be invoked after the form has been
>   submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked
>   after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the
>   following arguments:
>   1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
>   2.) statusText
>   3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
>   4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

So

```
var edit_form = {
    url: 'asdf/asdf',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (output, status, xhr, $form) {
        console.log('x',$form, status);
        $form.css("border-color", "green");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $form.css("border-color", "#323131");
        }, 3000);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error, $form) {
        console.log($form)
        $form.css("border-color", "red");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $form.css("border-color", "#323131");
        }, 3000);
    }
};
$('.twitch-form').ajaxForm(edit_form);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5bx2hwc2/)

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I still have no idea how to get that. Whats the name of that parameter or what should I do? as output are data from my document thats being called to.

Comment: change your function(output)  to function(output, statusText, xhr, form)

Comment: @digitaldouble Great, that works, I just used $form. Yep, the edited answer works great. Which one should I accept guys? As you both provided correct answer.

Comment: Your welcome. The link I posted in my post leads to that part of the documentation.

Comment: @digitaldouble Yes i found it its at the bottom, i really missed that one. Ooops :D well, its 5am here, so thanks again, now it works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here's how you create a success callback:

```
var options = {
    success: showResponse
    ...
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    ...
}
```

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: I accepted Aruns answer, as he posted it sooner, but really thanks to both of you. Too bad i cant accept two answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Read the API, In there provide available options... try this

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        var options = { 
          target:     '#divToUpdate', 
          url:        'comment.php', 
          success:    function(){ alert("Success ")},

          error:function(){
            alert("Error occurd");
          }

        }; 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);  





      }); 
    </script> 

       <form id="myForm" action="" method="post"> 
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
      Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
```